# XML escape character import in postgres

Tags: java, xml, postgresql

i am using postgres function to import xml data to postgres by the use of xpath. this data might contain xml escape character such that &lt ; . how to solve this problem knowing that i want to insert < instead of &lt ; in the database?
java(jpa) is used call the function. so what i need is a java api or postgres function to transform this escape characters.

**edit**

```
    create temp table temp2  on commit drop as
    select xpath('//detail/text()',x))[1] as detail
    from unest (xpath('/table/row',myxml)) x;
```

where myxml is:

```
<table> 
<row>

<detail> my xml data &lt;</detail>

</row>
</table>
```

temp table will be inserted into another table
actually i am finding `&lt;`  instead of <  in the new table.

Comment: These character entities like `&lt;` are only relevant to the XML parser. The strings you get out of a text node or an attribute after parsing don't contain the character entities but the original characters (`<` here). So there might be a problem with parsing the XML. Please show us the relevant code.

Comment: code update check this exampe @vanje

Comment: Ok, it seems, you are running into this problem: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAAY5AM3CjMcq2qMUX6gBPPcT+H9xDCjJb0tAGbrW3ra9SytJfA@mail.gmail.com

Comment: But this is too PostgreSQL specific for me, sorry.

Comment: so the solution replacing the data by custom method after xpath