# How to serialize ampersands in the XML document by the use of PostgreSQL

Tags: xml, postgresql

How to make xpath return the actual data not the escaped one for example:

If I use xpath to xml document that contains `&lt;`, the result is `&lt;` but `<` is desired.

How to get this desired result?

**Edit Example**

```
  select xpath('//A/text()',<A> &lt; <A>))[1]
```

will return   `&lt;` instead of <

Comment: Please can you post some example data and the query you are using at the moment

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27708254/xml-escape-character-import-in-postgres

Comment: @Rhumborl i have edited the question check the example. it seems it changed since postgres 9.3 as link vanje mentioned